# Atan2 strange output when calculating angles c++

Tags: c++, angle, atan2

I am trying to calculate the angle from a Point in based in a quadrant, but I am getting strange values for some quadrants and Its resulting in a incomplete operation for me.

Basically what I need to know is at what angle a object that has the center point (x1, y1). From the second object that has the center point (x2, y2), which is considered the center of the quadrant. x2, y2 will never be 0,0. Because its at some position in the screen.

So, I am doing the following code:

```
int y = point.center().y - quadrant.center().y;
int x = point.center().x - quadrant.center().x;
float angle = std::atan2(y, x) * 180/acos(-1);
//this was my try to fix the strange values that the code above is giving, but no sucess
float angle = std::atan2(y < 0 ? -y : y, x < 0 ? -x : x) * * 180/acos(-1);
```

I am getting the following strange outputs that are screwing with what Ill do after getting the exact angle.

[image]

Can you guys show me what is wrong here?

EDIT:

```
    int y = point.center().y - source.rect.center().y;
    int x = point.center().x - source.rect.center().x;
    float angle = std::atan2(y, x) * RAD_TO_DEC;
    Point ponta;
    Point raio = Point(source.rect.bottomRight().x - source.center.x,   source.rect.bottomCenter().y - source.center.y);
      if (angle >= 0.0f && angle <= 90.0f) {
         //right bottom
          ponta = point.bottomRight();
          raio = Point(source.rect.bottomRight().x, source.rect.bottomCenter().y);
          g_logger.info(stdext::format("Radius: y%d x%d, ponta x%d %y, x%d y%d - angulo: %f", raio.x ,raio.y, ponta.x, ponta.y, x, y, angle));
         if (ponta.x <= raio.x && ponta.y <= raio.y && ponta.x) {
             return true;
         }
      }
```

Comment: What are the values of `point.center().x` & `y` and `quadrant.center().x` and `y`? It looks like the first value is just an uninitialized value.

Comment: Please read what is [MCVE]

Comment: @Xabirau - please, don't post links to images of text. Simply post the text in the question. It's enormously wasteful of bandwidth (1,821 bytes instead of 88 bytes in this instance) and presents the possibility the question will be useless should the external site be down.

Comment: @user1118321 the values are higher than 0, but they vary. Not all values are outputing wrongly. Just a few, and it affects my results.

Comment: Can you show us some of the inputs when you get incorrect output? That would help us determine what's going wrong.

Comment: @user1118321 if you try this: float angle = std::atan2(384, 543) * 180/acos(-1); The output will be -2.0f. Else if you try: float angle = std::atan2(672, 479) * 180/acos(-1); The result is -268156158.. and more. As you will see in the print.

Comment: No, the result is not `-268156158...` , the result is `54.5188`. Please post more of your code so we can see what's actually going on. Please include the method you're using to print things out, too.

Comment: @user1118321 Ive updated the topic with the code

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in the code you posted. When you step through the code in the debugger, what does `angle` look like? I don't know what a `stdtext` object is, but maybe the problem is with that and not with your math? Also, the value you posted is a negative infinity, so maybe the inputs aren't what you think they are? You should definitely step through the code in the debugger and check the values going into each function.